# Apache Spark: How to use Python 3 with pySpark for development

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So far I have done following:

```
import os

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = '/usr/local/spark/'
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = '/opt/conda/bin/python'

from pyspark import SparkContext
```

But when I run I get the error:

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/opt/conda/bin/python -u /home/vagrant/src/spark.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/src/spark.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

Even If I try to run it without using Python3 path I get the same error.

The SPARK version of Python is given here:

```
/usr/local/spark/python
```

What wrong am I doing?

Ideally I want to use Python3 for my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

try to:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark')
```

or a direct way:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: I rather used `findspark.init`. Worked like Charm